# formatting list to convert into string

Tags: python, string, list, maya

Here is my question

```
count += 1
num = 0
num = num + 1
obs = obs_%d%(count)
mag = mag_%d%(count)
while num < 4:
   obsforsim = obs + mag
mylist.append(obsforsim)
for index in mylist:
    print index
```

The above code gives the following results

```
obs1 = mag1
obs2 = mag2
obs3 = mag3
```

and so on.

```
obsforrbd = parentV = {0},format(index)
cmds.dynExpression(nPartilce1,s = obsforrbd,c = 1)
```

However when i run the code above it only gives me

```
parentV = obs3 = mag3
```

not the whole list,it only gives me the last element of the list why is that..??
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the code above is capable of creating that output - maybe you could provide some more information.  For instance how is it that obs1 = mag1?  Is there a declaration statement somewhere that establishes that?

Comment: Could you add some more detail? The variable names are quite confusing. The topmost code shouldn't be returning anything 'equal' to anything, just print out each item in the list line by line.

What do you mean by "sforrbd = parentV = {0},format(index)"?

Try formatting the question in a generic way, including all starting variable values (obs, mag, etc...I see you're incrementing them, but from what?) and what you expect to see.

Comment: Yes the third line obsforsim = obs + mag

Comment: I eddied my question hope it can be understood now.

Comment: You are almost there but the code you have given is not enough yet, I don't think.  I think the while statement should loop indefinitely since num = 1 when the while statement executes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having difficulty interpreting your question, so I'm just going to base this on the question title.

Let's say you have a list of items (they could be anything, numbers, strings, characters, etc)

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,"abcd"]
```

If you do something like:
    for i in myList:
        print(i)

you will get:

```
1
2
3
4
"abcd"
```

If you want to convert this to a string:

```
myString = ' '.join(myList)
```

should have:

```
print(myString)
>"1 2 3 4 abcd"
```

Now for some explanation:
`' '` is a string in python, and strings have certain methods associated with them (functions that can be applied to strings). In this instance, we're calling the `.join()` method. This method takes a list as an argument, and extracts each element of the list, converts it to a string representation and 'joins' it based on `' '` as a separator. If you wanted a comma separated list representation, just replace `' '` with `','`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your indentations wrong ... it should be

```
while num < 4:
   obsforsim = obs + mag
   mylist.append(obsforsim)
for index in mylist:
```

but Im not sure if thats your problem or not

the reason it did not work before is

```
while num < 4:
   obsforsim = obs + mag
#does all loops before here
mylist.append(obsforsim) #appends only last
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual pythonic way to spit out a list of numbered items would be either the range function:

```
results = []
for item in range(1, 4):
    results.append("obs%i = mag_%i" % (item, item))

> ['obs1 = mag_1', 'obs2 = mag_2', 'ob3= mag_3']
```

and so on  (note in this example you have to pass in the `item` variable twice to get it to register twice.

If that's to be formatted into something like an expression you could use

```
'\n'.join(results)
```

as in the other example to create a single string with the obs = mag pairs on their own lines.

Finally, you can do all that in one line with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
'\n'.join([ "obs%i = mag_%i" % (item, item) for item in range (1, 4)])
```

As other people have pointed out, while loops are dangerous - its easier to use range